# Design editor wont show

Tags: android

I have installed https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html Android Studio and when I try to use it, I get these errors:

```
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
 Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
```

And I does not get the design editor to show anything.
Have anyone experienced this and/or have any advice?

Comment: "check logs for details" - so, did you do that?

Comment: You need to check the gradle build logs in the Gradle Console tab. Also, there should be an error just above the stacktrace, at the top of the window containing this snippet.